# How create json arry format with mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE streetuk_dev.ob_get_category_data()
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('name',type,
    'transaction_categories' , bud_sub_category))
    FROM ob_category  ;
END
```

**OUTPUT code when execute**

```
[
{"name": "income", "transaction_categories": "general_banking"},
{"name": "income", "transaction_categories": "credit_cards"},
{"name": "income", "transaction_categories": "loans"},
{"name": "Expense", "transaction_categories": "mortgage_and_rent"},
{"name": "Expense", "transaction_categories": "utilities"}
]
```

**What i expect JSON format**

```
[
   {
    "name": "income",
     "transaction_categories": [
                    "employment_income",
                    "credit_cards",
                    "loans"
                ]
   },
   {
     "name": "expense",
     "transaction_categories": [
           "mortgage_and_rent",
            "utilities",
          ]
   },
]
```

Anyone can resolve this? Help me to convert the code what i expected answer

Comment: You need aggregate transaction_categories, then add name.

Comment: Provide sample data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) which must give shown desired output.

Comment: @akina How can aggregate i always got the error

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT('name',type,'transaction_categories' , JSON_ARRAYAGG(bud_sub_category))
    FROM ob_category GROUP BY type ;`

Comment: this code show the duplicates